# Aligning Text To Left Using Brackets

Tags: html, css, editor, adobe-brackets

I've search all over but can not find a way to align lines of code using Adobe Brackets editor. It's like Stackoverflows' CTRL-K to push source code to the right only reverse to the left. Does anubody know?

Comment: Have you tried SHIFT+TAB?

Comment: Can you give some further clarification on the editor you are using and what you are hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Brackets Editor and I'm trying to align lines of code from right to left. Shift-Tab worked like Bluefire said but thanks to CalebB as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHIFT-TAB does it like Bluefire said.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Beautify extension for Adobe Brackets.